# Iterating through a dictionary of dictionaries with nested lists

Tags: dictionary, filter, ansible

I want to iterate over a dictionary of dictionaries with nested lists in Ansible. Let's take the following example:

```yaml
vars:
  my_outer_dict:
    my_inner_dict_1:
    - entry_1
    - entry_2
    my_inner_dict_2:
    - entry_3
    - entry_4
    my_inner_dict_3: []
```

I want to use a `loop` with the `subelements` filter. (Using Ansible core 2.14.8.)

I have come up with the following example:

```yaml
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  vars:
    my_outer_dict:
      my_inner_dict_1:
      - entry_1
      - entry_2
      my_inner_dict_2:
      - entry_3
      - entry_4
      my_inner_dict_3: []

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: '{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}'
    loop: "{{ my_outer_dict | subelements('value', skip_missing=true) }}"
    # Passing an empty string to subelements does the same thing
```

But it fails:

> Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ my_outer_dict | subelements('value') }}): the key should point to a dictionary, got '['entry_1', 'entry_2']'. the key should point to a dictionary, got '['entry_1', 'entry_2']'

What I don't understand is why the next task works:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: '{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}'
  with_subelements:
  - '{{ my_outer_dict | dict2items }}'
  - value
```

The output I want to see:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'my_inner_dict_1'}, 'entry_1']) => {
    "msg": "my_inner_dict_1 entry_1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'my_inner_dict_1'}, 'entry_2']) => {
    "msg": "my_inner_dict_1 entry_2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'my_inner_dict_2'}, 'entry_3']) => {
    "msg": "my_inner_dict_2 entry_3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'my_inner_dict_2'}, 'entry_4']) => {
    "msg": "my_inner_dict_2 entry_4"
}
```

So the question is: Is it possible to get the same behaviour of the `with_subelements` loop by using the `subelements` filter, if you don't want to iterate over a nested dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your translation from the *"`with_*`"* form to the *"`loop` plus filters"* form, you left out the `dict2items` filter which allows to translate your dictionary of dictionaries into a list and make it traversable, so, usable with the `subelements` filter:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ my_outer_dict | dict2items }}"
    ##  this one ------------^           
    - value
```

So, the correct translation here should have been:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}"
  ## Using YAML multiline to make the code more spaced
  loop: >-
    {{ 
      my_outer_dict 
        | dict2items 
        | subelements('value', skip_missing=true) 
    }}
  ## Using the `label` attribute of `loop_control`
  ## to make the output less verbose
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.0.key }}"
```

<sup>For YAML multiline, see *[yaml-multiline.info](https://yaml-multiline.info)*.</sup>
<sup>For a less verbose loop output, see *["Limiting loop output with label"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label)*.</sup>

---

So, given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}"
  loop: >-
    {{
      my_outer_dict
        | dict2items
        | subelements('value', skip_missing=true)
    }}
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.0.key }}"
  vars:
      my_outer_dict:
        my_inner_dict_1:
        - entry_1
        - entry_2
        my_inner_dict_2:
        - entry_3
        - entry_4
        my_inner_dict_3: []
```

It yields the expected:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=my_inner_dict_1) => 
  msg: my_inner_dict_1 entry_1
ok: [localhost] => (item=my_inner_dict_1) => 
  msg: my_inner_dict_1 entry_2
ok: [localhost] => (item=my_inner_dict_2) => 
  msg: my_inner_dict_2 entry_3
ok: [localhost] => (item=my_inner_dict_2) => 
  msg: my_inner_dict_2 entry_4
```